# How to Properly Do an Equivalence Test in an If Statement?

Tags: c#

In C# If Statements, I usually conduct equivalence tests like this:

```
if (isPrime == true)
```

but my friend says that's wrong or it wastes resources. He says this is the right way to do it:

```
if (isPrime)
```

He tried to explain, but I don't get why the condition is missing from the conditional check!

I know I'm a noob, but to me, it looks like there is only the left hand side of the equation in those brackets. Is my friend correct? Why?

Comment: It does not waste resources.... for readability sake both cases are fine.

Comment: both are exactly the same, we prefer the second one because it's shorter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are fine. In fact, they generate exactly the same IL:

```
bool isPrime = true;
if (isPrime == true);
```

and

```
bool isPrime = true;
if (isPrime);
```

generate

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // isPrime
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // isPrime
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0005:  ceq         
IL_0007:  stloc.1
IL_0008:  ldloc.1
IL_0009:  brtrue.s    IL_000B
IL_000B:  ret
```

If you have an `if` statement with only a left hand side statement (no equals sign) the compiler will try to implicitly cast your left hand side type to `bool`, then call the comparison operator on your left hand side and `true`. That's exactly what happens if you write `isPrime == true` as well, so there are effectively no resources being wasted, you have exactly the same code running.

However, there's a catch. You didn't specify the type of `isPrime`. If it's a nullable bool, as in `bool? isPrime`, then

```
bool? isPrime = true;
if (isPrime);
```

won't compile. In this case you are obliged by the compiler to do

```
if (isPrime == true);
```

Which is a bit wasteful as it involves a possibly unnecessary call to `Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault()`. If you do have a `bool?` and you know it has a value (maybe you've already verified it before), then you can use:

```
if (isPrime.Value);
```

Which doesn't require that call and will save you a few resources (compiler optimizations notwithstanding). Chances are you don't need this performance gain though, so go for readability.

If you're curious, I used [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to generate the ILs here, and I've also checked [the official implementation available for `struct Nullable<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs).

Comment: Your friend could be saying you're wasting disk resources (the file does get bigger) but that comment would only be useful as a joke.

Comment: Hi, can you amend with a source if you can find one? That would strengthen your answer.

Comment: @Code_Steel there you go

Answer (score 3):

Both ways are right

```
bool isPrime = true;
if(isPrime)
   return;
```

Or

```
if(isPrime == true)
   return;
```

If you work with **WPF** so it has occur error because all wpf controls are dependent objects which are dynamic (run time). i.e.:

```
if(button1.IsVisibility) // Wrong 
   return;

if(button.IsVisibility == true) // Correct 
   return;
```

I hope it will be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

They are both exactly the same. Since an `if` statement just resolves to `true` or `false` when you are testing a bool you don't need to compare it to anything.

For example:

```
if (isPrime == true)
```

and

```
if (isPrime)
```

are both equivalent and will pass if the value of `isPrime` really is true.

The inverse is also possible:

```
if (isPrime == false)
```

and

```
if (!isPrime)
```

are also equivalent for the same reason.

As for whether to use one or the other, it's entirely a personal or coding style choice. Some people prefer explicitly defining the if statement, some people (myself included) prefer keeping it simple but just testing the variable by itself. The compiler doesn't care and will reduce both to the same operations anyway.

Note the MSDN article for [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) uses this as it's main example.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is not missing. It is checking for `isPrime` is true. the same goes if you give `if(!isPrime)` it will checking for false.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tdorno 's comment it doesn't waste any resource.

if `isPrime` is `boolean` then it must be true or false. when you give it in a condition it just returns value of the variable.  If we have `int` variable it return only numeric values hence it's not correct.

for eg. you could use

```
if(true){
 //Statements
}
```

like wise `isPrime` return either `true` or `false`

```
if(isPrime){
 //Statement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if (isPrime == true)
```

or

```
if (isPrime)
```

both has the same meaning and there is no performance difference between them. But suggestions for best coding practices is to use if(isPrime) as there is small code.

Answer (score 1):

I view the second example as better but it won't make any difference to a compiler.  Programming languages are for humans, so what is more readable to the audience is best.

The first example is basically overstating that the case is true IMHO while the second is a bit more concise.

Programmers have had discussions about negation as well.

```
if(!isPrime)


if(isPrime != true)


if(isPrime == false)
```

Which do you like better? I still think the first is best because it's more concise.  However, there's no right answer for these.